# Piwik does not show stylesheets after moving its installation directory

Tags: matomo

I have moved my Piwik installation from `http://app.example.org/piwik` to `https://example.org/apps/piwik` by just moving all the files via SSH and updating the trusted hostname in the configuration.

When I log into Piwik now via the new URL, it does not show any stylesheets:

[image]

From the Firefox console I have gathered that it cannot load URLs like `https://example.org/apps/piwik/index.php?module=Proxy&action=getCoreJs&cb=2c24910fe084a280836d0fc58ce2c81f`. When I click on these URLs in the inspector, I do see some JavaScript or CSS. I don't really understand why this is happening.

In another Firefox profile, it just works. On mobile, Firefox (synced with the main profile), no CSS is shown. In Chromium on the desktop and Chrome on Android, it also works. So it must be something inherent to my Firefox profile.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Most likely your browser is blocking, rather than doing a inspect you should look at both Console and Network since inspect does not mean that the resource has been processed.

Comment: I have now tested with other browsers and profiles, the difference might be the addons, as @lukas-winkler just mentioned in his answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the time the coreJs and CSS of piwik fail to load because of an adblocker with an overly broad rule track blocks every URL including the string `piwik` or `Matomo`.

Disabling the adblocker on your Matomo (Piwik) page should fix the issue.

You probably already had an exception for `http://app.example.org`, but now that the domain is `example.org` it doesn't apply anymore.

Comment: Indeed, I have some additional filter rules against tracking in my content blocker, therefore it also blocks all the evil Piwik stuff on my domain. Disabling it for my own domain has fixed this.